# How to correctly use isAuthorized() from cakephp's AuthComponent in AJAX-calls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, authorization

I am using the the AuthComponent from the cakephp-core. So I use the isAuthorized()-Method to check any request.
For "normal" requests, this works just fine - when isAuthorized() returns false, the user is redirected to "where he came from" and with setFlash I can display a message what the authorization-problem is (if I want to).

But when it comes to AJAX-requests, this makes no sense of course. The response is then the page the user is currently on as responsetext... What I'd rather like is: If authorization fails on an ajax-call, send a response with status 400 (or whatever) and just the message "not authorized because you're not an administrator" (or whatever).

Is there an easy way to achieve that?

The only workaround that comes to my mind is creating a controller especially for all ajax-requests. In its isAuthorized()-Method it would (if authorization fails) redirect to an action with 1 parameter (the fail-message) and that action renders just this message. But (let alone that I don't know if that would work at all, if redirection if possible from isAuthorized(), but I guess it would) that seems quite... dirty/sloppy to me. So does someone know an easier/cleaner way?

I'd be happy about any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set json response with HTTP 401 code and terminate process like this:

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    if( ... ) {
        // Auth fails
        if($this->request->is('ajax')) {
            $this->response->type('json');
            $this->response->statusCode(401);
            $this->response->body(json_encode(array('status' => 'ERROR', 'message' => 'Unauthorized')));
            $this->response->send();
            $this->_stop();
        }
    }
}
```

In response body you can also set url where you want to redirect your user. Handle this redirection with javascript.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great!
What I'm doing now is putting nearly the whole isAuthorized-function in a try-block, if authorization fails, I don't immediately return false but throw an exception; then in the catch-block I check if the request is ajax or not, in the first case I use the code you gave me above, otherwise I just use setFlash.